How to remove manually made page numbers content controls with VBA?
I am aiming to create a wildcard expression for strings such as Pg. 125 or Pg. 397 and I believed it to be Pg\. ([0-9]{1,3}).
I have a document that has various page numbers that I have placed manually into the document and the number portion is a plain text content control:



The issue that I am running across is that when I use the find and replace module with the string it is not capturing it. It captures Pg. and ([0-9]{1,3}) separately, but not together.
Ultimately, the goal is to create a VBA macro that will reset the page numbers to their original placeholder texts and remove the current values so that I can re-number the pages when I update the template.
The below code is what I attempted to try and was not successful:
Sub FindAndEraseValue()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pattern As String
    pattern = "Pg. [0-9]{1,3}"
    
    ' Start from the beginning of the document
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Pg. [0-9]{1,3}"
        .MatchWildcards = True

        ' Loop to find all occurrences
        Do While .Execute
            ' Set the range to the found text
            Set rng = rng.Duplicate

            ' Identify the portion to keep (the "Pg." part)
            If rng.Text Like "Pg. [0-9]{1,3}" Then
                ' Replace the numbers with an empty string
                rng.Text = "Pg. "
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub


Have you tried escaping the dot .?

@DavidPostill - I have but it still didn't work

I think something like the following should work:
Sub trickymatch()
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim ccrange As Word.Range
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
With r.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = "[0-9]{1,3}"
  .MatchWildcards = True
  Do
    .Execute Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    If .Found Then
      If r.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
        If ActiveDocument.Range(r.Start - 5, r.Start - 1).Text = "Pg. " Then
          Set ccrange = ActiveDocument.Range(r.Start - 1, r.Start).ContentControls(1).Range
          If ccrange = r Then
            r.Text = ""
          End If
          Set ccrange = Nothing
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Loop Until Not .Found
End With
End Sub

Matching using wildcards is a problem because the beginning and end of the content control are represented by null characters, and that stops the pattern match process from matching the full pattern Pg. [0-9]{1,3}
You can see this if you select, say, Pg. 137 in your example text and use VBA to look at Selection.Text and Selection.Characters.
Selection.Text will be Pg. 137 as expected, and Len(Selection.Text) will be 7.
But Selection.Characters.Count will either be 8 or 9 (depending on whether you selected the end of the Content Control or not). Characters 1 thru 4 will be Pg.  , and 6 thru 8 will be 137, but if you try to look at AscW(Selection.Characters(5)) you will see an error.
If you try:
Dim s As String
s = Selection.Characters(5)
Debug.Print Len(s)

You will I think see 0. This actually matches vbNullString (and not vbNullChar, which is technically different).
Further, the VBA Like operator only lets you use some wildcarding, but not the {1,3} construct that you have in your code.
So the idea of my code is to look for digit strings of up to 3 digits. If one is found, ensure that it is in a content control and is preceded by Pg. . If so, make sure that the digit string is the same length as the content control content (otherwise it could actually be a 4-digit string, for example). If so, set the string to "").
That's just a quick attempt at a solution. But depending on your text, it might be simpler to look for the text Pg. and look for a following content control instead.

Does this version capture non-content control plaint text with that Regex string?

It will find any digit string with 1 to 3 characters, but the If .Found block should ignore the ones that aren't in a content control or are not the same length as the containing control. So if you have a lot of digit strings it may be faster to look for Pg. instead. Or you might be better off looping through content controls looking for ones that have 1-3 digits in them and avoid Find altogether. Also, I haven't looked at scenarios where there is a more complex nesting of content controls.
